# Array mudando de ordem

Tags: javascript, array

Eu sou novo em javascript e estou fazendo um pequeno jogo para aprender a linguagem. A ideia é simplesmente pedir para o usuário dizer a sequência do número pi e, em caso de erro, parar o programa e dar uma pontuação ao usuário. Estou executando o programa no node.

Este é meu código:

```
let rl = require('readline')


//funcao para copiar método format do python
String.prototype.format = function() {
    var s = this,
        i = arguments.length;

    while (i--) {
        s = s.replace(new RegExp('\\{' + i + '\\}', 'gm'), arguments[i]);
    }
    return s;
};

let prompt = rl.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout)

// Array contendo a sequencia do número pi
let array_pi = String(Math.PI).replace('.','').split("")

prompt.question('Please, type the pi value:', function(exp){
    let i = 0
    while (array_pi[i]==exp){
        prompt.question('Next:', exp)
        i++
    }
    console.log('Wrong answer!.Your score was {0}'.format(i))
    process.exit()
})
```

O problema é que a condição dentro do **while** está sempre dando **false** mesmo quando eu dou o número verdadeiro. Parece que o JS está rearranjando a array. É normal isso? Como faço para ele manter a array na ordem que coloquei?

Comment: resposta a comentário apagado:O que pensei foi o usuário jogar um número por vez. Se jogar 3, o programa pede o próximo, se jogar 1, pede o próximo, and so on. Suponha que o usuário jogue 7 no terceiro, aí dá erro e o programa termina. Então a comparação seria `array_pi[i]==exp` mesmo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é causado pelo fato de a função .question() ser assíncrona. Ou seja, o que está depois dela é executado independentemente do que está dentro (que é executado depois que o usuário tecla enter). Isso se resolve chamando recursivamente a função (ou seja, a função chama ela mesma).

Este é um engano clássico no Javascript.

Código funcionando:

```
let rl = require('readline')


//funcao para copiar método format do python
String.prototype.format = function() {
    var s = this,
        i = arguments.length;

    while (i--) {
        s = s.replace(new RegExp('\\{' + i + '\\}', 'gm'), arguments[i]);
    }
    return s;
};

let prompt = rl.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout)

// Array contendo a sequencia do número pi
let array_pi = String(Math.PI).replace('.','').split("")


let funcao = function(indicePi) {
    prompt.question('Entre o digito de PI para o algorismo ' + (indicePi+1) + ': ', function(exp){

        if((array_pi[indicePi] != exp)) {
            console.log('Wrong answer!.Your score was {0}'.format(indicePi))
            process.exit()
        }
        else {
            indicePi++;

            // chamar recursivamente a função
            funcao(indicePi);
        }
    })  
}

let indicePi = 0;
funcao(indicePi);
```